# mysql limited count per day

Tags: mysql, date, count, limit

```
SELECT user_id, date_time, journal_id FROM logs WHERE user_id = 1
```

```
user_id |       date_time     | journal_id
   1   | 2014-02-04 11:15:00 |     21
   1   | 2014-02-04 11:25:00 |     22
   1   | 2014-02-04 14:00:00 |     31
   1   | 2014-02-05 10:15:00 |     33
   1   | 2014-02-05 12:55:00 |     45
   1   | 2014-02-05 15:15:00 |     48
   1   | 2014-02-05 15:35:00 |     49
   1   | 2014-02-06 05:00:00 |     62
   1   | 2014-02-06 13:40:00 |     67
   1   | 2014-02-06 15:00:00 |     72
```

I would like to select the first 3 rows for each date (*note that the 5th of feb. has 4 rows), and I was thinking if its do-able with count or limit, but without any luck.
I have been looking for solutions, but havent had any luck. Mostly I would really like to know if it's do-able with MySQL, or if I just have to do some date checking in PHP instead, to remove the unwanted rows from the result.

The actual result I'm aiming for would be this:

```
user_id |       date_time     | journal_id
   1   | 2014-02-04 11:15:00 |     21
   1   | 2014-02-04 11:25:00 |     22
   1   | 2014-02-04 14:00:00 |     31
   1   | 2014-02-05 10:15:00 |     33
   1   | 2014-02-05 12:55:00 |     45
   1   | 2014-02-05 15:15:00 |     48
   1   | 2014-02-06 05:00:00 |     62
   1   | 2014-02-06 13:40:00 |     67
   1   | 2014-02-06 15:00:00 |     72
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if i understand correctly, you wants to display like first four rows in that table...

Comment: Yes. It's do-able with MySQL. Solutions to this problem are widely discussed - here and elsewhere. Someone will no doubt provide another one in a minute.

Comment: @jmail: i want 9 rows, the first 3 of each day.

Answer (score 1):

Working solution:

```
select user_id, date_time, journal_id from (
  select 
    user_id, date_time, journal_id
    , @crid:=
      (case when @pdt=(@cdt:=date_format(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d')) 
                 then (@crid+1) 
                 else (@pdt:=@cdt)/@pdt 
       end) as grouped_row_num
  from logs, ( select @crid:=0, @cdt:=0, @pdt:=0 ) r
) results
where grouped_row_num <= 3
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the following

- Create a stored procedure where the cursor is the date
- Select the rows from the table with a limit and copy those results to a new table

An example how i would make it:

`CREATE PROCEDURE SHOW_FIRS_ROWS (IN TABLENAME VARCHAR(50))<br/>
    DECLARE varSQL VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE varDATE VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE no_more_rows INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE  cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date_time) FROM logs;
    DECLARE  CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET  no_more_rows = 1;
OPEN  cursor1;
FETCH cursor1 INTO varDATE;<br/>
REPEAT
    SET @varSQL = CONCAT("INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM logs WHERE DATE(date_time) = ", varDATE ," LIMIT 0,3");<br/>
   PREPARE stmt FROM @varSQL;<br/>
   EXECUTE stmt;<br/>
   FETCH cursor1 INTO varDIR;<br/>
   UNTIL no_more_rows = 1 END REPEAT;<br/>
CLOSE  cursor1;<br/>
END`